# Going from "While using the app" to "Always" and viceversa from code

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Is it possible to change the users settings from "While using the app" to "Always" location type, and viceversa? Obviously, once the user has accepted to share both types of locations. I don't want to make the user go open the settings and change it, if he has already allowed both types.

Comment: Your app can only have one kind of authorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only make a call to authorise a service such as Location Services once. Once the user has input their choice, this can only be changed from the device's settings manually by the user.

It's worth noting that since iOS 8, you can programatically launch the Settings app using the following call:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];`

or in Swift:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))`

Hope this helps!